# How to resolve the inconsistency between the reference number in the text and bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies

Suppose my text has three references A, B, and C. If I cite them in order, the corresponding numbers are consistent. However, if I change the order in the bibitem, the numbers are inconsistent. For example,

```
"I refer to \cite{A}, then \cite{B}, then \cite{C}."
```

And the bibliography is

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem{C}
cccccccc
\bibitem{B}
bbbbbbbb
\bibitem{A}
aaaaaaaa
\end{thebibliography}
```

The output is this:
 "I refer to [3], then [2], then [1]."
To fix this, I should switch the first and third bibitems, but suppose I am writing a paper with more than 50 references, and after revising the paper I notice that I should add another reference somewhere in the text. In this case the easiest way is choosing a name for the reference, say `\cite{myforgotten}` and add it to the bibitem. But, as we saw, it causes an inconsistency. Is there any way to fix this, or I have to put the bibitems exactly in order?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There's a reason BibTeX and BibLaTeX have been invented. You probably want to use one of them instead of your thebibliography environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be mixing up two conceptually very different things: the "key" of an entry, and the number that the entry is assigned, assuming numeric-style citation call-outs are in use (as would appear to be the case for your code snippet).

- The "key" of each bibliographic entry. In your code snippet, you've named the keys `A`, `B`, and `C`. More frequently, the keys are selected to be at least somewhat mnemonic of the associated entry. E.g., if a piece was authored by Adam Jones and Zebedee Smith in 2007, one might choose the key of that piece to be `jones-zebedee:07`.
- The "number" that's assigned to each entry. The numbers are critically important for numeric-style citation call-outs; for authoryear-style citation call-outs, the numbers are nearly irrelevant and are generally not even shown.

If one builds the `thebibliography` by hand, each `\bibitem` must feature the required argument, which is the `key`. Each `\bibitem` can also feature an optional argument, which will help determine what the citation call-out will look like. If the optional arguments of the `\bibitem`s are omitted, the formatted bibliographic items will be numbered consecutively in ascending order, and the citation call-outs will also consist of numbers (often, but not always, surrounded by square brackets).

Suppose that the hand-built `thebibliography` environment looked like this:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem[66]{C}
cccccccc

\bibitem[1001]{B}
bbbbbbbb

\bibitem[77]{A}
aaaaaaaa

\end{thebibliography}
```

LaTeX would use the number 66 for citation call-outs to the item with key `C`, the number 1001 to the item with key `B`, and the number 77 to item with key `A`. The *ordering* in which the items would appear in the bibliography would be C, B, and A. If you were to re-order the items by hand, so that A comes before B and C comes after B, but don't change the optional arguments, they'll still be numbered 77, 1001, and 66.

Building bibliographies by hand is both exceedingly tedious and highly error-prone. If you foresee writing more than a couple of working papers using LaTeX in your career, you'll do yourself a huge favor by learning the basics of creating bibliographies using software tools such as `natbib`, `biblatex`, BibTeX, and biber.